# Why do I get "too much recursion"

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I am trying to build a function that takes two arguments(integers) and builds an array from all the integers that stand between them, provided by the user through the form.
I am getting the message "too much recursion" in the console. I have an infinite loop I guess. How do I break out of it so it only prints the array list[] in the div via .innerHTML ?

This is the function with the loop:

```
var fNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
var sNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);
var list = []
var i;
    function calculate() {
        for( var i = fNum; i <= sNum; i++){
            list.push(i);
            break;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = list;
        }
        calculate();
    }
```

Here is a Bin: http://jsbin.com/EcOtUJIx/2/

Comment: calculate is called inside of the function itself, so there is no way for it to stop calling itself therefore you get too much recursion

Comment: If you could explain what it is you think this function should do, it might be possible to suggest ways to fix it. As it is, all I can do is tell you why it's doing what you're seeing it do; I can't tell what the point of it is supposed to be however.

Comment: @Pointy: It needs to get two integers and fill in the array with all the integers between the two integers from the form.

Comment: Well then just get rid of the `break;` and the recursive call, and move the DOM update to *after* the `for` loop.

Comment: Dont attemp coding without a perfect algorithm. It will go in vain.

Comment: Why do you down vote the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code as

```
var fNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
var sNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);
var list = [];
function calculate() {
    for( var i = fNum; i <= sNum; i++)
    {
        list.push(i);
    }
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = list;
}
calculate();
```

Answer (score 4):

Your function is written such that it *always* calls itself. There is no way for the process to stop, so that results in "too much recursion".

The function also has a logic error in the loop, which *always* exits after adding a single value to the list. There's no condition around that `break;` statement, so the subsequent DOM call is never executed. That is, your code is equivalent to:

```
function calculate() {
  list.push(fNum);
  calculate();
}
```

That simpler function will fail in exactly the same way, of course.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is all what you need. You don't have to use recursion to do the task.
Here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ukuTafUk/1/)

```
function calculate() {
     var fNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
     var sNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);
     var list = new Array()
     for( var i = fNum; i <= sNum; i++){
          list.push(i);
     }
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(list);
}
```